# Gzip Compression and leverage Browser Cache Not working for my store

Tags: php, .htaccess, optimization, magento-1.9

I am trying to optimize my store, I have added Gzip Code and Leverage Browser Cache Code in my `.htaccess` File:

```
# Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
# End of Leverage browser caching using mod_expires #

# Leverage browser caching using mod_headers #
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Expires "Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# End of Leverage browser caching using mod_headers #
```

Comment: Have you checked that those modules actually are enabled in Apache? And how are you checking if it's used or not?

Comment: Good question you asked,keep asking and share knowledge here@Randhir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enable Apache mod_headers and mod_expires modules**

> Please check mod_expires and mod_headers are enable or not on your store through the below code.

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

> If both extension not unable to your server,please follow following steps:-

**Step 1 :-**

> Now login to server using SSH console and continue below steps:

**To enable mod_headers:**

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

**To enable mod_expires:**

```
sudo a2enmod expires
```

> **Step 2 :-**
>
> after completing the server update, you need to restart Apache server
>   to make these changes effective. Enter below line in your SSH console
>   to restart Apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

> Or else reboot your server by following code in SSH:

```
reboot
```

Use following code in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     # YEAR
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
          Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
     </FilesMatch>
     # WEEK
     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf|woff)$">
         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
     </FilesMatch>
     # 45 MIN
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
     </FilesMatch>

     Header set Connection keep-alive

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|asp|html)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

After clear your store cache and reload your website URL,recheck gtmetrix tool or whatever you are using tool.

Comment: Thank you such great explanation in details, you made my day.. Now working fine and i have checked on GTmetrix tool my website speed look good.thank once again@Umesh Kumar

Comment: Great explanation,Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for GZIP compression

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>

   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
   BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
   Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

and for Leverage browser caching your code is correct but if its not working then you have to check that mod_expires and mod_headers modules are enabled or not on your server.